# python re match equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, python-3.x

In Python, you can use re.match(pattern,str) to get the matched groups through "()". For example, if I have:

```
str = "My name is Derek Last Name"
re.match("My name is (.+)",str).group(1)
//output is "Derek Last Name"
```

Is there a way to achieve the same functionality in Javascript?

Thanks

Derek

Comment: A bit more searching would've probably done it for ya. [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression)

Comment: You are right. I saw it but I thought it was a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the match function.

```
> var str = "My name is Derek Last Name"
undefined
> str.match(/My name is (.+)/)[1]
'Derek Last Name'
```